# How to remove entries in replication set in MongoDB (Ubuntu)

Tags: mongodb

I need to manually remove a replication set entry that is read by rs.conf().

```
 {
       "_id" : 1,
       "name" : "10.2.0.4:27017",
       "health" : 0,
       "state" : 8,
       "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
       "uptime" : 0,
       "optime" : {
               "t" : 0,
               "i" : 0
       },
       "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
       "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-06-04T09:08:39Z"),
       "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
       "pingMs" : 0
}
```

Could you please let me know where this information resides, I have checked the mongod.conf file under etc/ and the details are not in that.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [`rs.remove(ip)`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.remove/#rs.remove) to remove a member from a replica set.

Comment: I cannot connect to a primary as there is no primary hence cannot use rs.remove()

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the same procedure for force-promoting an orphaned secondary to remove the leftover entry.

```
> cfg = rs.config()
> cfg.members.pop() // remove the entry from the members array
> rs.reconfig(cfg, {force: true})
```

MongoDB docs: [Reconfigure a Replica Set with Unavailable Members](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/)
Thanks to this SO answer: [Promote secondary to primary from secondary node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632490/503463)